# ¿Este código esta bien implementado o puede ser más optimizado?

Tags: javascript, api, express, mongoose, http

Estoy desarrollando una REST API con ayuda de Express.js y Mongoose. Por cada personaje que se guarda en la base de datos, tengo una clave llamada "url" la cual contiene unicamente los endpoints de la URL, una vez llegamos a la función a través del metodo POST para mostrar todos los personajes, concateno los endpoints con una variable de entorno que se encarga de guarda la URL base.

Al mismo tiempo, utilizo un metodo .map para organizar todos los datos y regresarlos en la petición, pero considerando que pueden haber hasta 100 personajes, quisiera saber si esto es realmente optimizado o si hay mejores maneras de hacerlo.

El código de las funciones para las request:

```
const Animatronic = require('../models/animatronicModel');
const Games = require('../models/gamesModel');
const Types = require('../models/typesModel');
const Humans = require('../models/humansModel');

const animatronicCtrl = {
    getList: async (req, res) => {
        try {
            const animatronics = await Animatronic.find().populate('type');
            if (animatronics.length < 1) return res.status(404).json({ msg: 'Not Found' });

            const animMap = animatronics.map(anim => {
                return {
                    id: anim.id,
                    name: anim.name,
                    type: anim.type,
                    techInf: anim.techInf,
                    createdBy: anim.createdBy.map(human => {
                        return {
                            name: human.name,
                            url: `${process.env.HOST}${human.url}`
                        }
                    }),
                    appearances: anim.appearances.map(game => {
                        return {
                            name: game.game,
                            url: `${process.env.HOST}${game.url}`
                        }
                    }),
                    url: `${process.env.HOST}${anim.url}`
                }
            });

            console.log(animMap);

            res.json({ animMap });
        } catch (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({ msg: err.message })
        }
    },
    uploadAnim: async (req, res) => {
        try {
            const { id, name, type, techInf, createdBy, affiliations, appearances, url } = req.body;
            if (!name) return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'Name required' });
            if (!id) return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'Id required!' });

            const animExist = await Animatronic.findOne({ name });
            if (animExist) return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'Animatronic already exists' });

            const gameList = await Games.find().where('id').in(appearances);

            const humanList = await Humans.find().where('id').in(createdBy);

            const appearRef = gameList.map(game => {
                return {
                    id: game.id,
                    game: game.name,
                    url: `/games/${game.id}`
                }
            });

            const createdRef = humanList.map(human => {
                return {
                    id: human.id,
                    name: human.name,
                    url: `/humans/${human.id}`
                }
            });

            const newAnim = new Animatronic({
                id,
                name,
                type,
                techInf,
                createdBy: createdRef,
                affiliations,
                appearances: appearRef,
                url
            });

            await newAnim.save();
```

El modelo:

```
const mongo = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = mongo;

const animatronicSchema = new mongo.Schema({
    id: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    type: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Types'
    },
    techInf: {
        type: Object,
        default: {
            genre: "Unknown",
            mainColor: "MainColor",
            eyeColor: "EyeColor",
            accs: ""
        }
    },
    createdBy: {
        type: Array,
        items: {
            type: Number
        }
    },
    affiliations: {
        type: Object,
        default: {
            game: "Unknown",
            url: ""
        }
    },
    appearances: {
        type: Array,
        items: {
            type: Number,
            trim: true
        },
        required: true
    },
    url: {
        type: String
    }
}, {
    timestamps: true
});


module.exports = mongo.model('Animatronics', animatronicSchema);
```

Alguna idea??

Comment: Al parecer hay muchos `map` que sobran. Si tienes el objeto `A` y quieres retornar el mismo objeto `A`. No hay necesidad de hacer un map, simplemente trabaja con el objeto y punto

Comment: Si estás haciendo todos esos `maps` solo para modificar la URL, porque no usas entonces la funcion toObject/toJSON de mongoose para hacer ese cambio? Eso te permite olvidarte de modificar todos los endpoints donde uses el module para ajustar su url... sencillamente la cambias en el modelo y siempre que vayas a devolver esa instancia como un json se ejecuta ese metodo.